# Solving a limit sum involving Cantor sets

Tags: integration, measure-theory, summation, closed-form, cantor-set

Let $P:C\to \mathbb{R}$, where $C$ is the Cantor set and $P$ is continuous. If [$C_n$ is the sequence of numerators](https://oeis.org/A306556) from the values of endpoints from the defined intervals of iteration $k$

$0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9, 18, 19, 20, 21, 24, 25, 26, 27, 54, 55, 56, 57, 60, 61, 62, 63, 72, 73, 74, 75, 78, 79, 80, 81, 162, 163, 164, 165, 168, 169, 170, 171, 180, 181, 182, 183, 186, 187, 188, 189, 216, 217, 218, 219, 222, 223, 224, 225, 234, 235, 236, 237, 240, 241, 242, 243,...$

Where $C_1=0$, find the exact value of

$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{2^{k+1}} P\left({C_n}/{3^k}\right)}{2^{k+1}}$$

1. For $P=x^2$ (According to Mathematica, the closed-form is $3/8$).
2. For $P={1}/{\left[2(x+2)\right]}$. $\left(\text{According to mathematica, it seems the closed form is} \left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^{-1-2e}\cot(e\pi)\cos(e\pi)\ \right)$
3. For $P=2^x$ (Doesn't appear to have a closed-form in fact most functions don't give a closed form.)
4. For $P$ in general (In terms of Integrals, Measure, etc.). This should solve my newly defined average for functions defined on the Cantor set.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your Mathematica code to find $C_n$? I wrote a recursive definition using the OEIS site but it's not practical.

Comment: For powers $p=0,...5$, for $P(x)=x^p$, I got the sequence $$ \left\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{8},\frac{5}{16},\frac{87}{320},\frac{31}{128},\frac{10215}{46592
   }\right\}$$

Comment: Here is the codes `cantormesh[n_Integer?NonNegative] := Nest[Replace[#, {x_?NumberQ, y_?NumberQ} :> Apply[Sequence, Partition[Subdivide[x, y, 3], 2]], 1] &, {{0, 1}}, n]` and `With[{c = Flatten[N[cantormesh[13], 30]]}, Mean[c^(1/5)]]`

Answer (score 1):

**Tl;dr:** there is a recursive formula for monomials based on their degree given in a 1992 paper.

To start, I gathered some numerical evidence. For $0\le m,n \le 6$ I asked Mathematica to evaluate $\int_{C_m} x^n H^s(dx)$. For each fixed $n$, the partial sums had the formulas
$$
\left\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{3^{-2 m}}{8}+\frac{3}{8},\frac{1}{16} 3^{1-2
   m}+\frac{5}{16},\frac{9^{1-m}}{32}-\frac{17\ 9^{-2 m}}{320}+\frac{87}{320},-\frac{17\ 9^{-2
   m}}{128}+\frac{25\ 9^{-m}}{64}+\frac{31}{128},-\frac{17}{512} 9^{1-2 m}+\frac{29\
   9^{1-m}}{512}+\frac{3253\ 9^{-3 m}}{46592}+\frac{10215}{46592}\right\}$$

Taking $\lim_{m\to \infty}$ you just keep the constant terms:

$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{8},\frac{5}{16},\frac{87}{320},\frac{31}{128},\frac{10215}{46592}
   \right\}$$

I didn't recognize this sequence and it was somewhat intractable (RSolve, FindSequenceFunction, oeis were stumped). So I googled the sequence; *amazingly* I got a hit from a 1992 paper. Unfortunately, the paper was in Mandarin, of which I am wholly illiterate. So I asked a good friend to translate and she graciously agreed. Several months later, she emailed me a working draft. I'll give the main points from that paper and will link my edited version and the original (she asked that her version not be distributed).

- One establishes that integrating with the Hausdorff measure is well-defined and agrees with the Riemann sum definition for continuous $f$.
- Using a recursion formula for the right endpoints of each subinterval, one obtains the functional relation
  $$
  \int _F f(x) H^s(dx ) = \int _F f(x) H^s(dx ) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\int _F f\left(\frac{x}{3}\right) H^s(dx )+\int _F f\left(\frac{x}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\right) H^s(dx) \right)
  $$
- In particular, if we let $\alpha_n =\int_F x^n H^s(dx)$, with $\alpha_0=1$, then

$$\alpha_n = \frac{1}{2(3^n-1)}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{n}{k}2^k\alpha_{n-k};$$

this is immediate from linearity and the binomial theorem. One checks that these values agree with the first few that we computed.

- For continuous functions $g$ on $[0,1]$, one argues analogously: fix $\epsilon>0$ and use the Stone-Weierstrass theorem to approximate $g$ uniformly by a polynomial to within $\epsilon$. Then use the recursion to integrate the polynomial.
- The translation was tricky at this point, but I think one can unite the Hausdorff measure with a 'singular' measure. The idea is to take a piecewise constant function on $[0,1]\setminus C_m$ and take the supremum to yield a function $h$ that is continuous with $h'(x)=0$ a.e. This induces a measure $\mu_h$, after which
  $$
  \int _F f(x) H^s(dx) = \int _0^1 f(x) \mu_h(dx)
  $$
- The rest of the paper talks about self-similar sets (of which the [ternary] Cantor set is one) and generalizes the similarity transformations to different parameters. In particular, there is a section on the von Koch curve that I have omitted.

---

I tried and failed to replicate some of the calculations you mentioned in your post. In particular, I'd love to see how you got the value of $\left(\frac{1}{e}\right)^{-1-2e}\cot(e\pi)\cos(e\pi)$ for that one function.

---

- The original paper: http://fzgx.xpu.edu.cn/OA/pdfdow.aspx?Sid=199203
- A link to my summary: https://docdro.id/mJp25vh
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension